# Dynamically add pictures from Web to ImageView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

I have a code similar to [this](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/).

And like in there I want to add pictures dynamically to my ListView using a SimpleAdapter, but instead of having the photos on the Drawable resources I want to grab mine from the web. I already have a method that gets a url and returns a Drawable and I want to add the id of that Drawable to the HashMap like he does. How to I get that id (R.drawable.blabla) ?

Btw here's the method

```
   public static Drawable loadImageFromWeb(String url) {
         try {
             InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
             Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
             return d;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return null;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever that guy is doing isn't the best way to go about it, use a https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html base adapter and override the getview method

Answer (score 3):

Adding a new Drawable Resource at runtime is not possible. Resource ID's and data are generated while editing and bundled into your APK at build time.

Instead create a local cache and load files from there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to solve the issue with this:

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/

Very good source, thanks all.